# How to use FileReader in rust wasm?

Tags: rust, webassembly

This is part of my code, the error in rest `move |event: Event|`

```rust
pub struct FileStream{
    el : HtmlInputElement,
}
impl FileStream {
    pub fn new(el : HtmlInputElement) -> FileStream {
        FileStream {el}
    }
    pub fn get_file(&self){
        let file = self.el.files().unwrap().get(0).unwrap();
        let file_reader = FileReader::new().unwrap();
        file_reader.read_as_data_url(&file).unwrap();
        let onloadend = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |event: Event| {
            let file_reader = file_reader.unchecked_into::<web_sys::FileReader>();
            let data_url = file_reader.result().unwrap();
            let data_url = data_url.unchecked_into::<JsValue>();
            let data_url = data_url.as_string().unwrap();
            let audio_el = self.el.unchecked_into::<HtmlAudioElement>();
            audio_el.set_src(&data_url);
        }) as Box<dyn FnMut(_)>);
        file_reader.set_onloadend(Some(onloadend.as_ref().unchecked_ref()));
    }
}
```

I don't know how to fix this error...

```bash
error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `FnMut` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`
  --> src/lib.rs:29:48
   |
29 |           let onloadend = Closure::wrap(Box::new(move |event: Event| {
   |                                         -        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `FnMut`
   |  _______________________________________|
   | |
30 | |             let file_reader = file_reader.unchecked_into::<web_sys::FileReader>();
   | |                               ----------- closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `file_reader` out of its environment
31 | |             let data_url = file_reader.result().unwrap();
32 | |             let data_url = data_url.unchecked_into::<JsValue>();
...  |
35 | |             audio_el.set_src(&data_url);
36 | |         }) as Box<dyn FnMut(_)>);
   | |__________- the requirement to implement `FnMut` derives from here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0525`.
```

Answer (score 0):

When the closure is created, it moves `file_reader` into itself (because it is declared as a `move ||` closure). Then, when the closure is *called*, it consumes `file_reader` via calling `unchecked_into()`. Therefore, if the closure were to be called a second time, it would no longer have a `file_reader` to use. That's why the compiler decides the closure is only a “`FnOnce`”.

On the other hand, the `set_onloadend` callback mechanism wants a function that can be called more than once, in case the underlying event somehow happens more than once.

The general solution to this problem is to adjust your function so that it *can* be called more than once — as far as the compiler is concerned. You can do this by putting the value that must be moved in an `Option` outside the closure, then using `Option::take()` inside the closure to get it back out — thus leaving the `Option` value to be `None` if the function ever gets called again.

However, in this case, it would be simpler to just remove the entire `unchecked_into()` line. As far as I can see, there is no need for it, because the object is already typed as a `FileReader`. (But I haven't tried compiling your code to see if it works without, so maybe I missed something.)